# How can I show that in an elastic collision i can set $| \vec{v_2} - \vec{v_1} | = | \vec{v_2}' - \vec{v_1}' | $?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, conservation-laws, collision

I am getting stuck in a really easy problem in Statistical Mechanics that involves elastic collisions, it is really very shameful that I am getting stuck at such a simple thing, but from:

$$\|\vec{v_1}\|^2 +\|\vec{v_2}\|^2 = \|\vec{u_1}\|^2 +\|\vec{u_2}\|^2$$
and $$\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2} = \vec{u_1} + \vec{u_2}$$

How can I get $$\|\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1}\|=\|\vec{u_2}-\vec{u_1}\|$$

I tried completing the square in the first equation like:

$$\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_1} +\vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{v_2} -2\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2}= (\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1})\cdot(\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1})=\|\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1}\|^2= \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_1} +\vec{u_2}\cdot\vec{u_2} -2\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2}$$

and then using the second equation to get:

$$=\vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_1} +\vec{u_2}\cdot\vec{u_2} -2\vec{v_1}\cdot(\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2}-\vec{v_1})$$

but I cannot seem to be able to simplify this to $$\vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_1} +\vec{u_2}\cdot\vec{u_2} -2\vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2} = \|\vec{u_2}-\vec{u_1}\|^2$$

Can someone help me with this? I am sure it is quite simple, but since I am stuck I am losing way too much time on this.

Comment: The algebraic solution to this problem is very far from simple.  If you ever have the option, use the solution that involves the center of mass reference frame.

Comment: Hum?@DavidWhite Could you elaborate on that ? You mean that if I try to solve this problem in the reference frame of the center of mass I can diminish the number of variables and solve directly, whithout resorting to that squares trick that I had forgot ?

Comment: Yes.  The center of mass reference frame makes this problem much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm typing in mobile so I'm ignoring all the vector signs. The problem is to show that
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$$
and
$$a + b = c + d$$
Gives you
$$|a - b| = |c-d|$$
From the second eq you get by squaring both sides
$$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab = c^2 + d^2 + 2cd$$
Using the first equation you then get
$$ab = cd$$
Now subtract $2ab= 2cd$ on both sides of the first equation and you get
$$(a-b)^2 = (c-d)^2$$
Which is the required answer. To get the vector equivalent just replace the regular product with the dot product.

Comment: It is really a talent to write all that latex on mobile

Answer (score 5):

Use the *reduced mass* identity to write the total energy as
$$
\frac 12 m_1 |{\bf v}_1|^2+ \frac 12 m_2 |{\bf v}_2|^2\\=
\frac 12 \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2} |{\bf v}_1-{\bf v}_2|^2+ \frac 12 (m_1+m_2)|{\bf v}_{CofM}|^2.
$$
Then, if energy is conserved (definition of elastic) we must have that $|{\bf v}_1-{\bf v}_2|$ is the same before and after.